# SSIS underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, ssis, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to make a call to an API within a SSIS package. I am able to use the same code in a regular unit test class and everything works as expected. I tried some of the recommendations I've seen in stack overflow but no luck.

It fails at the GetRequestStream()

Error: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Inner Error Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Code:

```
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestURL);
            var muaRequest = new MUARequest
            {
                designationType = "MUAP"
            };
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(muaRequest));

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            request.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            //var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Results>(content);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    results.ErrorCode = "Http Request Failed.";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Were you able to make successful POST call using postman?

Comment: @FaisalMehboob yes, i found the issue the security protocol needs to be placed before the creation of http web request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of the security protocol needs to be called before the creation of the web request. After that it works